# Change terminal output (log) file while it is written

Tags: bash, terminal, logfile

I'm saving the terminal output in a log file ($ command > logFile) and it becomes quite large. I only need to keep say the N most recent lines. Is it possible to limit the line number, so that if the number of N lines is exceeded for each new line the first/oldest line is deleted?

Or: If I try to change the file (deleting the oldest lines automatically with a small script), bash aborts writing the output to the logFile. Is there a way to continue writing the terminal output to the file even if it accessed by another programm/script (which I assume is the problem here)?

Comment: there is a tool called `logrotate`, you can set several conditions there. But there are many other solutions like `sponge `  and so on

Comment: @Max Muster - thanks for the hints, unfortunately with `sponge` there appears the same problem, the writing is aborted. `logrotate`, as I understood, deals with entire files, not the specific content. Please correct me, if I'm wrong

Comment: Maybe this https://gist.github.com/CAFxX/571a1558db9a7b393579 is doing the trick.